# Heroku: how to transfer database from the existing application to the new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I want to create the new application from the existing one using Heroku.

I cloned the old app to the new one and changed old name to the new one on Heroku.

I’ve transferred the environmental variables using as below:

```
$ heroku config -s -a existing-heroku-app > config.txt
$ cat config.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs heroku config:set -a new-heroku-app
```

`DATABASE_URL` for the new application was created automatically when I've cloned the existing application and I could not change it using edit option on Heroku.

How to transfer database from old application to the new one?

**Updated:**

I tried as below

```
$ heroku pg:copy old::postgres://cbnedduwickhsw:c30d4bf09f3f0e756e6360b9331e8b001c70b6dc5c2c4cee899e71ad972f3f23@ec2-55-165-254-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d9egrorbiba5at postgres://gjducqczpmibkn:0c7e9eecead030222792675a076c8980e8bd6edf2f68ba38465fbe978097445a@ec2-184-76-153-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfa8rqk1n47ec0--app new-staging
```

But have error

```
-bash: postgres://gjducqczpmibkn:0c7e9eecead030222792675a076c8980e8bd6edf2f68ba38465fbe978097445a@ec2-184-76-153-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfa8rqk1n47ec0--app: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You forgot whitespace before `--app`. Just use names of databases instead of values of theirs URL. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#direct-database-to-database-copies) documentation

> You can also transfer directly from a database on another app:
>
> `$ heroku pg:copy sushi::ORANGE GREEN --app sushi-staging`
>
> This would copy data from the `ORANGE` database of the `sushi` app to the `GREEN` database in `sushi-staging`. This could be used to copy production data into a staging app for testing purposes.

Usually there just one database per one Heroku app.

So you can run it as

```
$ heroku pg:copy old-app::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL --app new-app
```

Replace only `old-app` and `new-app` with your data.

Comment: Wow! I put your command as is only change app names  and after 1 seconds  all data was transfer!  probably was some extra space in my option(: thanks.
I'll give you a credit but i want to see if all those email errors go away.